# AppleScript error "Can’t make \"" into type integer." number -1700

Tags: integer, applescript

I know this error has been covered here but I have been searching through the answers for days now and when I think I have cracked it I end up breaking the code somewhere else.

I am trying to run AppleScript in Xcode to make a backup of a folder on a set network machine.

The problem I am having is that the backup is date stamped and in a sub folder on the users Desktop.
I am trying to avoid using hard POSIX paths to make the final app universal.
All the solutions I have found don't take this in to account.

I apologize for the messy code but I am still learning AppleScript and so end up hashing different bits of code together. my code is

```
set catFolder to "Catalyst AA"
set bckup to "Backups"
set myDesktop to path to desktop folder as alias
set main_folder to ((path to desktop folder) & "Backups") as string

tell application "Finder"
if not (exists folder (bckup) in myDesktop) then
    set main_folder to (make new folder at desktop with properties {name:bckup}) as      alias
else

    if not (exists folder (catFolder) in main_folder) then
        set cat_folder to (make new folder at folder main_folder with properties {name:catFolder}) as alias
    end if
end if

end tell



try
mount volume "afp://10.0.0.1/Content SSD AA/Catalyst/Catalyst 4.40_m373_HD"

set d to (year of (current date) as text) & "-" & (month of (current date) as integer as text) & "-" & (day of (current date) as text) & "-" & (time string of (current date))
tell application "Finder"
    set f to make new folder at POSIX file "~/Desktop/Backups/Catalyst AA" with properties {name:d}
    duplicate POSIX file "/Volumes/Content SSD AA/Catalyst" to f
end tell
try
    tell application "Finder"
        eject disk "Content SSD AA"
    end tell
end try
end try
```

the error file is

```
tell application "Finder"
path to desktop as alias
    --> alias "Macintosh HD:Users:ben:Desktop:"
path to desktop
    --> alias "Macintosh HD:Users:ben:Desktop:"
exists folder "Backups" of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:ben:Desktop:"
    --> true
Result:
error "Can’t make \"Catalyst AA\" into type integer." number -1700 from "Catalyst AA" to   integer
```

I appreciate it if someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

Thanks for your time

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set folderPath to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "Backups/Catalyst AA"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderPath

try
    mount volume "afp://10.0.0.1/Content SSD AA/Catalyst/Catalyst 4.40_m373_HD"
    set d to (year of (current date) as text) & "-" & (month of (current date) as integer as text) & "-" & (day of (current date) as text) & "-" & (time string of (current date))
    tell application "Finder"
        set f to make new folder at POSIX file folderPath with properties {name:d}
        duplicate POSIX file "/Users/unimac/Desktop/output.csv" to f
    end tell
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            eject disk "Content SSD AA"
        end tell
    end try
end try
```

Comment: adayzdone that worked perfectly thank you very much I was starting to give up. I never thought of using a do shell script :)