# How to copy a file to another file in the same folder using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have the following AppleScript:

```
to copyMovieTemplate(sermonCode)
    local iMovieProject
    set iMovieProject to ((iMovieSermonsPath as text) & sermonCode & ".rcproject")

    display dialog ("Copying " & (sermonTemplate) & " to " & (iMovieProject as text))

    tell application "Finder"
        duplicate file sermonTemplate to file iMovieProject without replacing
    end tell
end copyMovieTemplate
```

The `sermonTemplate` and `iMovieSermonsPath` variables are `aliases`:

```
global sermonTemplate
global iMovieSermonsPath

set sermonTemplate to alias ((iMovieSermonsPath as text) & "Sunday Service Template.rcproject")
set iMovieSermonsPath to alias ((iMovieProjects as text) & "Sermons:")
```

When I run this script, I get the an error telling me that Finder can't copy the target file to the target file:

> Finder got an error: Can’t set file "Macintosh HD:Users:vitabile:Movies:iMovie Projects.localized:Sermons:14-0101-01.rcproject" to file "Macintosh HD:Users:vitabile:Movies:iMovie Projects.localized:Sermons:14-0101-01.rcproject".

What am I doing wrong?  What's the right way to do this copy?

**Edit 1**

I even tried removing the `without replacing` clause and there was no difference.

**Edit 2**

After some more searching, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766733/applescript-error-cant-make-into-type-integer-number-1700), plus the feedback in the comment, so I rewrote my code:

```
-- Copy the Sunday Sermon Template file to the iMove Projects folder
to copyMovieTemplate(sermonCode)
    -- Convert the sermonCode into a file name for the iMovie project
    set iMovieProject to sermonCode & ".rcproject"

    display dialog ("Copying " & (sermonTemplate as text) & " to " & iMovieProject as text)

    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set theCopy to duplicate alias sermonTemplate to folder alias iMovieSermonsPath
            set name of theCopy to iMovieProject
        on error errStr
            display dialog ("Unable to copy the Sunday Sermon Template project to " & (iMovieSermonsPath as text) & iMovieProject & ".")
            display dialog "Error: " & errStr
            error number -128
        end try
    end tell
end copyMovieTemplate
```

This is still not working, but the error has changed:

> Finder got an error: Can’t make alias "Macintosh HD:Users:vitabile:Movies:iMovie Projects.localized:Sermons:" into type integer.

Using System Events didn't work as I got the same error.

Comment: See my second edit to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my problem.  The path I was constructing for the iMovie Projects folder didn't contain a colon at the end.  That is, I was constructing a path that looked like this:

> Macintosh HD:Users::Movies:iMovie Projects.localizedSermons:

When it should have looked like:

> Macintosh HD:Users::Movies:iMovie Projects.localized:Sermons:

Once I added the missing colon, it started to work.

I also got rid of the aliases and just kept everything as `text`.  I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

As for `set iMovieSermonsPath to alias (iMovieProjects as text) & "Sermons:"`: you're making the same mistake you made in your previous question ([what is the correct path to the iMovie Projects folder to use in an AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22433142/45375)):

Instead of creating a single alias, your code inadvertently creates a *list* whose first entry is an alias of the folder whose path is `iMovieProject as text`, and whose second element is the string literal "Sermons:"

To fix this, *parenthesize the entire expression that builds up the path string* before passing it to `alias`:

```
set iMovieSermonsPath to alias ((iMovieProjects as text) & "Sermons:")
```

Comment: That was a transcription error.  The entire expression after the word `alias` is parenthesized.  I will edit the original question to reflect the fact.  I'm still getting the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: Got it. In your second snippet you're defining `sermonTemplate` in terms of `iMovieSermonsPath`, even though you're only defining `iMovieSermonsPath` AFTER that.